I'm trying to write a foreach script calling sed
I'm trying to write a foreach command using sed, something like:
foreach f (*csv)
sed -f xsed $f > tp.$f.tp
end

where:
xsed contains:
gsed -f xsed $f > tp.$f.tp


That should be: sed -e s/,/\t/g $f > tp.$f.tp

@s3dev , this is csh (or tcsh)

@LesterIngber, show what you have tried. Also, explain concisely what you are trying to do with the sed command (presumably replacing comma by tab - but you need to confirm that), finally confirm that you are using CSH or TCSH

I notice a few syntax issues, what shell are you using?
Here is a corrected version assuming you are using csh or tcsh:
foreach f (*.csv)
        sed 's/,/\t/g' "$f" > "tp.$f.tp"
    end

But if you are using bash, it would be like this:
for f in *.csv; do
    sed 's/,/\t/g' "$f" > "tp.$f.tp"
done


@LesterIngber, you may optionally accept this answer if it answered your question by clicking on the ✔️. This marks your question as having been answered and rewards both the asker and the answerer with reputation points. This is preferable to adding comments since comments can be deleted at any time for any reason.
